# How to avoid racing issues using Cloud Firestore Triggers

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm using **Cloud Firestore onCreate triggers on Firebase**, where client is a React Native app.

Users are getting points by writing in a separate collection which has `onCreate` triggers attached. User can create multiple single-point documents one after the other.

Example: 
User 1 gets 3x100 points. This creates three documents and trigger is triggered three times.

First executiong finds last user point amount (for example 500) increases it by 100, and saves new state = 600 into user profile. 
Meanwhile, before this has finished, second trigger is triggered, reads previous state which is still 500 since the previous trigger isn't finished, increases it by 100, and saves 600 also. 
Third one manages to do the same.

In the end user should have gotten 500 + 100 + 100 + 100 = 800 points, but he has 600 only because last trigger has been triggered before the first one has finished updating user profile and all inbetween changes are overwriten.

How to tackle this?

Thanks.

Comment: You should have a look at [Transactions and batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to make sure that all access to a common document is performed atomically.  This will ensure that competing writes don't clobber each other's updates.  In the event that there is a race to update, the transaction handler will be retried with updated data.

Comment: Thanks, I found it in the meantime. It's a bit hard to land on that page or maybe I've googled the wrong keywords.

Comment: Hey @Doug is this compatible with three separate onCreate triggers? I've tried to implement it as said in the documentation, but I still get one value update from three separate onCreate trigger value changes. Thanks.

Comment: The source of the change doesn't matter.  It could be any backend or client code.